# Exploring Causal Relationship in R

Tags: r, causality

I need to explore if there are any causal relationships in my dataset, but the data has 30 points per year (for 30 different countries) and only 10 years worth of data. Accordingly, I can't use Granger-Causality, because the time frame is too limited for each country, and because for each year there are multiple data points. So I was wondering what other types of causality analysis I can apply to the data, if there are any.

Comment: The name of that test is misleading, R cannot tell you anything about causality. You can only assess whether your data can predict its later observations (and thus hopefully future observations) well.

Comment: As @FransRodenburg pointed out, no software will ever tell you anything about causality in your data. That is something only domain-knowledge can provide. As much as R is concerned, blond parents are as much of a cause for blond children as blond children are for blond parents